# Bots that use UptimeRobot keeps getting rate limited

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

I used UptimeRobot and it worked well until about March 2022. Nowdays, my bots keep getting rate limited for some reason. I have 8 bots using UptimeRobot right now, currently two bots have been down since 22th March 2022 which is a total of 319 days. According to UptimeRobot, the cause is a 404 not found.[[image: 404 not found (404)]
Btw I'm using nextcord (a fork of discord.py)

If you're gonna suggest another website, please make sure you don't need to pay to use it.

If you need more information/my text was unclear, please leave a comment.

Thanks.

EDIT: Some of my bots are up in UptimeRobot, but ain't online in discord.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple users host their Bots in the same site (for example replit) they all share similar IPs (I will not explain this in detail)

What is happening is that the Discord API is ratelimiting the IP where your Bot is running. However, the webserver does not crash on Bot's errors (such as 429) so the site will be still online for uptime robot.

I would suggest to look for other free hosts but where you need a credit card to use the service (e.g. oracle cloud)

Comment: so you mean that my problem is not with uptimerobot?

Comment: yeah, it shouldn't be uptime robot, what host are you using?

Comment: im using replit